# NumberFormatException because NULL not recognised on prepared statement Java

Tags: java, null, prepared-statement

I am using a prepared statement to insert to my database. Some of the values im inserting are NULL as the matches are yet to be played, and so the score is NULL, NULL.

```
void insertFixtures(List<String[]> fixtures) throws SQLException {
    String query = "REPLACE INTO games (team1_id, team2_id, score1, score2, created_at, winner) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    Connection con = DBConnector.connect();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

    for (String[] s : fixtures) {

        int winner;
        stmt.setString(1, s[0]);
        stmt.setString(2, s[1]);

        String nullTest1 = s[2];

        if (nullTest1 != null) {
            stmt.setString(3, s[2]);
            stmt.setString(4, s[3]);
            stmt.setString(5, s[4]);
            int score1 = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
            int score2 = Integer.parseInt(s[3]);
            System.out.println(score1);
            System.out.println(score2);
            if (score1 > score2) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if (score2 > score1) {
                winner = 2;
            } else {
                winner = 0;

            }

            String gameWinner = Integer.toString(winner);
            stmt.setString(6, gameWinner);
        } else {
            System.out.println("empty");
            stmt.setString(3, null);
            stmt.setString(4, null);
            stmt.setString(5, s[4]);
            stmt.setString(6, null);
        }

    }
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
```

InsertFixtures takes the list string array and inserts these into my database using a for loop.
The problem i have is with:

```
if(nullTest1 != null ){
```

When i run this code in debug mode and set nullTest1 to equal null it skips over this and goes into the else statement. However, when i run it real time it goes into this if statement and has an issue with parseInt on a null value.

This is an example of the strings im trying to insert into my database:

```
Fixture 45 42 1 0 1554642300 
Fixture 49 48 null null 0
```

Any help is useful.
Thanks

Comment: *Unrelated:* You need to move the `stmt.execute()` inside the loop.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a `"null"` instead of a `null`? --- Anyway, catch the exception and print/log the value of `s` at the time it happens, so you can at least see what is going on. **Show us the stacktrace** and the output.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `null` before parsing a `String` into `Integer`:

```
int score2 = s[3] != null ? Integer.parseInt(s[3]) : 0;
```

You need to decide what should be the value if `s[3] is null`. I have put `0` just for example purpose.

Comment: Can i not insert NULL into my database, or even just a blank value?

Comment: Yes you can use `Integer score2` instead of `int score2`  and then `Integer score2 = s[3] != null ? Integer.parseInt(s[3]) : null;`

Comment: Whilst using this null specific line im still getting NumberFormatException for input string null. Do you have anymore advice or need anymore info?